# install nwjs dev version automaticaly when npm i

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, nwjs

is there a way to install dev version of nwjs automatically from package.json like when I type npm install?

Like when i type npm i nw --nwjs_build_type=sdk

I tried setting environment variable like this in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"preinstall": "set NWJS_BUILD_TYPE=sdk"}
```

but it did not work?

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install
```

install all required dependencies of node project. if you want to add another package then you have to install specific package

For Example :

```
npm i nwjs
```

or

```
npm i [package name, another Package name]
```

Comment: I want to install specific build type of nw.js - sdk version but I dont know how to specify this in package.json. I can manually install it by npm install nw  --nwjs_build_type=sdk

Answer (score 1):

I created new file .npmrc
and pasted this:

nwjs_build_type=sdk